# Pipe grep matches to less (or similar)

Tags: linux, bash

I need to go through a large log and I want to see each match (with several lines before and after each match) on a single screen or at least in a way that I can scroll/jump from match to match.

```
cat some.log | grep -B5 -A10 <regex>
```

I'd like to be able to go from match to match by piping it to less or by some other means. I can get the first N matches easily with the `-m` option but I'd like to know if there is a neat way to do what I want: jump from match to match. I could write a small function that adds the numbers from the before and after flags, adds 1 (for the line matching itself) and then tails it, but there might be a built-in Linux function that already does what I want.

Comment: Useless use of cat

Comment: And `man less` suggests `less -p <regex>`

Answer (score 2):

You can open the log directly with "less". Using "-S" as option the lines will not be wrapped. You can then enter "/" and your regexp to search for the lines you're interested in. With "n" you can jump to the next match. And you can scroll easy with the cursor keys.

Answer (score 1):

try use `grep` + `less`

```
grep -B5 -A10 <regex> some.log | less
```